# Why can I use 'another' in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, determiners

I'm translating the next sentence

> I got other of those calls yesterday

However I've found that the correct answer is this

> I got another of those calls yesterday

I understand that I can use "other" with plural nouns and if there is a singular one I must use a determiner before it, "another" can be used with singular nouns but in the sentence we are talking about "those calls".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that sentence, if you mean you got several more of those calls, then the correct pronoun is "more", not "other":

> I got **more** of those calls yesterday.

If you insist on using "other", you would have to use the plural form:

> I got **others** of those calls yesterday.

But, for reasons I can't think of right now, this is grammatical, but not natural English.

A natural place for "other" in the plural sense is directly before a *noun*:

> I got other *similar calls* yesterday.

Comment: I use "other" as an adjective and "another" as either an adjective or a noun. So, I would not say "I got others of those calls," but I would say "I got other similar calls," or (without the word "similar") "I got other calls."

Comment: @Chaim "Other" can have many more parts of speech than just adjective, the problem here is that "other" cannot be used before an "of"-phrase . Everything else you say is correct